# How to authorize access to static files based on claims

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authorization, claims-based-identity, static-files

Static files can require the user to be *authenticated* as [per documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

I have not been able to find any info on restricting *authorized* access to static files, according to specific claims.

E.g. users with claims "A" and "B" have access to folder A and B, where as users with only claim "B" only have access to folder B

How would I accomplish this "as easy as possible" with .NET 6.0 / webAPI / static files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is no built-in way to secure wwwroot directories, I think you can expose an endpoint, and then make judgments in the endpoint, This is a very simple method as you expected, in your question, you want to access static file `A` only user with claims `A`,I write a similar demo here, hope it can help you to solve your problem.

First I have a static file named "AAA" in `wwwroot`.

I use `Asp.Net Core Identity` here, Now I am logged in as a user, Then I add claim to this user.

```
//the claim's type and value is the same with static file name
Claim claim = new Claim("AAA", "AAA");

await _userManager.AddClaimAsync(user,claim);
```

Then I expose an endpoint to get the static path then do judgments :

```
//Add [Authorize] attribute, the controller can only be accessed when the user is logged in 

[Authorize]
public class TestController : Controller
{
//Pass in the name of the static file that needs to be accessed, and then use claim to authorize
    public IActionResult Find(string path)
    {
        var value = IHttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Claims.Where(e => e.Type == path ).Select(e => e.Value).FirstOrDefault();
        if(value !=null && value == path) {

             //authorize success
            //read the static file and do what you want
            
        }else{
            //authorize fail
        }
    }
}
```

**View**

```
//use asp-route-path="AAA" to pass the value of path
<a asp-controller="Test" asp-action="Find" asp-route-path="AAA">AAA</a>

<a asp-controller="Test" asp-action="Find" asp-route-path="BBB">BBB</a>

//.......
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer..  I am not using views in my case, but pure API / static files. I feared I had to follow something like this using an [HttpGet] attribute and some implementation of FileResult.  I'll mark this as an answer for "as easy as possible" until something more "built in" might show up ;)

Comment: @noontz Thank you for marking my answer, Actually, I want to write a demo use middleware to achieve it firstly, But I think it's a bit complicated to do that, So I write this answer. I refer to a lot of information, but it seems that there is no simple answer, I will continue to pay attention to this question, and if I find a better answer, I will  update it under this question.

Answer (score 2):

From the linked example;

```cs
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
});
```

You could build any policy you want, by calling any of the `.Require...` methods. eg;

```cs
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireClaim("name", "value")
        .Build();
});
```

Note that the fallback policy applies to *all* endpoints that don't have any `[Authorize]` metadata.

Instead, you will probably need to write some middleware to check your authorization rule for each path. Perhaps based on [this sample](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/main/src/Security/samples/StaticFilesAuth).

The linked example demonstrates an interesting concept. Authorisation is based on endpoints, but the static file middleware just takes over the response without using endpoint routing. So what if we generated our own endpoint metadata based on the file provider;

```cs
.Use((context, next) => { SetFileEndpoint(context, files, null); return next(context); });
```

That's doable, but what if we just defined a fake endpoint?

```cs
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
    endpoints.MapGet("static/pathA/**", 
        async (context) => context.Response.StatusCode = 404)
        .RequireAuthorization("PolicyA");
});
```

Of course you could map that dummy path to a controller.

Comment: Thanks for the input..  I was unaware of the .RequireClaim, but as you say, it applies to all endpoints (static files in this case), and writing middleware is, hmmm,  not "as easy as possible", for me at least ;)